# Which website would you propose for learning Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm working in a project and I need to use reactjs

> ***.Which website would you propose for learning Reactjs***

Comment: Going through the [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) will get you far.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to React from other programming environments can be a bit confusing. When I started learning React, I found that Kirupa Chinnathambi's video tutorials were really good at explaining how to **think** in React.

- https://www.kirupa.com/react/

You should also check out the official React tutorial:

- https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

I first started working React by using with CRA (`create-react-app`), but I found out that learning and working using `Next.js` was much more efficient. You should give that a try as well.

- https://nextjs.org/learn/